# tmux ctrl-b pauses application? how to scroll without pausing

Tags: linux, tmux, scrolling

I am running an application on Linux with tmux and notice that sometimes when I want to scroll the buffer, I pause the application.

How can I scroll without pausing the application? I tried following the commands [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82850/how-can-i-scroll-screen-or-tmux-buffer-without-pausing-the-application) but the buffer only seemed to be the current screenshot, so I would benefit from a more detailed explanation of what to do / why.

Comment: What is the output of `tmux -V`? Can you upgrade? According to the changelog one of the changes from 3.1c to 3.2 is "[Change copy mode to make copy of the pane history so it does not need to freeze the pane](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/e3a8b8434cf656164d74ae115ebccd432144ed2c/CHANGES#L452C3-L453C19)". My tmux is 3.3a and there is no problem.

Comment: Aha, it says `tmux 3.0a`. Thanks!